# Table Issues, reading multiple entries seperatly

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm currently having an issue with doing **If Statements** so that it reads and lines that the duplicated separately.

[image: The Table]

So I have the current code:

```
<?php

            $query4 = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM administrators WHERE habbo = 'Fists'" );
                $num   = $db->num( $query4 );

                while( $array4 = $db->assoc( $query4 ) ) {

            ?>
<?php if ( $array4['position'] == '{D} - Drill Instructor Academy' ) { ?>
<strong> Level 1 Works </strong>
<?php if ( $array4['position'] == '{C} - USMC Core Values' ) { ?>
<strong> Level 2 Works </strong>
<?php } 
} ?>
```

However it seems to be reading from the same line as it outputs only Level 1 Works but not Level 2 Works.

Any Ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Oh god there is so much wrong with that code. Go and do some basic tutorials... Props for at least not using **mysql** as most do when learning.

Comment: Any chance you can suggest a fix?

Comment: There is no single fix, there are lots of fixes needed. 1. You don't have any usernames of `Fists` so your query is returning nothing, the habbo column is where Fists resides. You don't have any columns named `{D} - Drill Instructor Academy` or `{C} - USMC Core Values`, they are both values of the `position` column. As I said, go and do some tutorials, you're getting even the basics horribly wrong.

Comment: Would that Edit I made be any better?

Comment: Yes, you've fixed 2 things. Tabulate properly and you'll notice broken stuff like this. You're not closing the first if statement.before running the second if statement so you can never output Level 2 works.

Comment: Ahh I see where I've messed up, thanks for the help Styphon.